# Display a date formatted in C++

Tags: c++, time

I try to display the current date in the format yyyy/mm/dd in the console in C++ using ctime but I come up against a display of numbers that have nothing to do with it or it displays nothing. How can I assign my date to a variable without any problem? Isn't there another way to display the date?
Thank you in advance.

I'll show you what I've done

```
class Emprunt{

private:
string datePret;
string dateRendre;
Adherent adherent;
Livre livre;

public:
time_t actuel = time(0);
tm *ltm = localtime(&actuel);
int year = 1900 + ltm->tm_year;
int month = 1 + ltm->tm_mon;
int day = ltm->tm_mday;
int hour = 1 + ltm->tm_hour;
int minute = 1 + ltm->tm_min;
int sec = 1 + ltm->tm_sec;
string date = year + "-" + month + '-' + day;

Emprunt(Adherent adh, Livre livre){
    this->datePret = date;
    this->dateRendre = "nothing";
    this->adherent = adh;
    this->livre = livre;
    livre.setLibre(0);
    adh.setNbLivreMax(adh.getNbLivreMax()-1);
}};
```

The only way that works is when I display the variables month, year, date in a cout 
(like this: `cout << "Date: " << year << "-" << month << "-" << day << endl;`)
but that's not what I want, I want to put it in a variable and assign it in a constructor.

Comment: [`strftime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/strftime) to a temporary `char` array, then assign to the string.

Comment: Use the [`std::put_time`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time) manipulator?

Comment: BTW, you can save some typing time by not using `this->` and accessing members directly.  The `this->` syntax is need only to differentiate member from parameters, *when they both have the same name*.  You can get around this by using different names between parameters and members.